# jquery - removing image area select from an image when my modal window closes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the jquery plugin 'image area select' http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/ to crop images which are uploaded by my users.

When a user uploads an image file the php I use to upload the file returns the file location on the server and fires a modal window. To this modal window I use .prepend to add the image to #myModal like so:

```
$('#myModal').prepend('<img id="photo" src="../'+success+'" />');
```

Then I attach the image area select code to this uploaded image.

```
$('#photo').imgAreaSelect({aspectRatio: '1:1', handles: true, fadeSpeed: 200,  onSelectChange: preview});
```

My issue is that if select an area of the image with imgAreaSelect and then click to close the modal window, the modal dissappears but the outline of the image plus the cropping handles are still there!

In the javascript which closes my modal window I've tried adding:

```
$('#photo').imgAreaSelect('');
```

to detach imgAreaSelect but that and other variations didn't work. Anyone any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
$('#photo').imgAreaSelect({disable:true,hide:true});
```

more option's  http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/usage.html

Comment: Hey, that doesn't seem to work like it should. When the modal window closes there's still the darkened background and the cropping handles there until you click on them. I also tried removing the css from #photo.css('') but no use either

Comment: Hi I updated my question with a live example. If you fancied taking a look I'd be grateful

Comment: Hey there. Looks like I was trying this in the wrong place! It works now. Thanks!

Comment: @ZaphodBeeblebrox I'm also facing the same issue, where did you place it ? need some help

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

> Option
>
> **remove**     If set to true, the plugin is completely removed.

So we assume it is

```
$("#photo").imgAreaSelect({remove:true});
```

**EDIT**:
Try this:

```
var myCroppable = $('#photo').imgAreaSelect({aspectRatio: '1:1', handles: true, fadeSpeed: 200,  onSelectChange: preview});
```

that goes wherever you are calling your `imgAreaSelect` right now. Now you have an instance of it. And then you do the following either at the Close button or at the Save Thubmnail button:

```
myCroppable.cancelSelection();
```

That should work.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond. I've updated my question with a live example. I'm still trying to fix this :(

Comment: @ZaphodBeeblebrox sorry that it is giving you so much trouble. I was a work and then busy and did not see your message until now. Try the edited code and see if it works.

Comment: Hi Hanlet, thanks for taking the time to take a look again. I tried your suggestion but unfortunately it didn't work. I tried it in a few places and also some variants which I thought might work but no luck. I'm very new to javascript, I'm probably doing something stupid!